# Постраничная навигация Codeigniter

Tags: jquery, php, codeigniter, sql

Здравствуйте. Сделала постраничную навигацию, но работает она по следующему принципу:

```
/page/3
/page/6
/page/9
/page/12
```

А как сделать именно, чтобы было

```
/page/1
/page/2
/page/3
/page/4
```

Помогите расширить пагинацию. Поиск не помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А в документации не искали?

```
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: сожгите меня на костре